# Nuxt router, going deeper than nuxt-child

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt Child components, but also want to link deeper past the child.

I think this explains it best.

```
example.com/cars               <-- cars.vue (has nuxt-child)
example.com/cars/bmw/          <-- cars/_maker.vue (this is the child)
example.com/cars/ford/         <-- cars/_maker.vue (this is the child)
example.com/cars/bmw/i3        <-- cars/_maker/type.vue (shows wrong template)
example.com/cars/ford/mustang  <-- cars/_maker/type.vue (shows wrong template)
```

`_type.vue` is not rendered, it uses the `_maker.vue` template instead.

I have no extended routes setup, it's purly off the directory structure routing.

How do I get the `/i3` and `/mustang` routes to use the `type.vue` template?

I think I can do it by not using Nuxt-Child and doing something like this, but I loose the good Nuxt-Child behavior.

```
example.com/cars               <-- cars/index.vue
example.com/cars/bmw/          <-- cars/_maker/index.vue
example.com/cars/bmw/i3        <-- cars/_maker/_type.vue
```

Comment: Please try : cars/_maker/_type/index.vue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the structure on `pages` folders like this.

```
pages/
--| _cars/
-----| _maker/
--------| _type.vue
--------| index.vue
-----| _maker.vue
-----| index.vue
--| _cars.vue
--| index.vue
```

Just add the `<nuxt-child/>` in `_cars.vue`, `_maker.vue` and `_type.vue` and remove the `index.vue` files if you don't need it.
.